# Broken Packages problem

Tags: linux-mint

My os: Linux Mint 17.1 (x64) + Cinnamon

I tried to make my linux play wma files and i broke something, because i can't play any videos now. What i tried:

- deleting `~/.gstreamer-1.0` folder
- running `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` (maybe this broke my system?)
- trying to install some libraries through apt-get (for example those having libavcodec in name and possibly others)

Now when i try to run mplayer i get the error:

```
> mplayer
mplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Other players (vlc) don't work either. So i tried updating my system. `sudo apt-get update` throwed some errors:

```
(...)
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Get:21 http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/upstream i386 Packages [30,0 kB]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
(...)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade` didn't work at all:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 audacity : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installed or
                     libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but it is not installed
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed or
                   libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed
 gstreamer1.0-libav : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installed or
                               libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but it is not installed
 libavdevice53 : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed or
                          libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed
 libavfilter3 : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed or
                         libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed
 libavformat54 : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed or
                          libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not installed
 libchromaprint0 : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installed or
                            libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.10) but it is not installed
 libopencv-highgui2.4 : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installed or
                                 libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.10) but it is not installed
 mencoder : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installed or
                     libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.11) but it is not installed
 mplayer : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installed or
                    libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.11) but it is not installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installed or
                    libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.18) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

then i tried `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
folder-color-switcher gir1.2-nemo-3.0 nemo-emblems
nemo-folder-color-switcher python-nemo python-psutil
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
libavcodec54
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libavcodec54
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 2715 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7309 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libavcodec54
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/ trusty/main libavcodec54 amd64 7:1.2.6-1~trusty1
404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec54_1.2.6-1~trusty1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Then i run `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` which gave me similar errors to `sudo apt-get update`.
I also tried synaptic package manager, which during start stated "You have 11 broken packages on your system!...". I tried `Edit => Fix Broken Packages` which appeared to do nothing (not even throw an error).  Then i chose "Broken dependencies filter", marked all packages there for reinstall and after several screens i got errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec54_1.2.6-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_1.2.6-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/libavdevice53_1.2.6-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/libavfilter3_1.2.6-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/pool/main/f/ffmpeg/libavformat54_1.2.6-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
```

So anyone knows what/how did i break and how can i fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

- Open "Software Sources"
- In PPA tab search for entries with "ffmpeg" in name and remove all of them
- Then run these commands in terminal (they update/clean whole system. If you don't want to upgrade distro you may omit the line with `dist-upgrade` part):

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f install
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  # sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- Optionally install mplayer and/or vlc for playing video/audio files:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mplayer
  sudo apt-get install vlc
  ```

and everything works as usual again.

Answer (score 0):

Easier (if you have Synaptic)

- Open your terminal and run `sudo synaptic`
- In Synaptic navigate to Settings > Repositories
- Find the repositories that are giving you errors.

  Here you can either "disable" or select and delete.
  *When you are done with the repositories make sure to press OK and let Synaptic do its trick.*
- Quit Synaptic and confirm

  Press "ctrl + Q" and **make sure you quit Synaptic** and not just minimize it otherwise apt-get will return in use error.
- Open your terminal and run `sudo apt-get update`

And there you have it, no more errors :)

*Hope it's understandable, only used Linux a week so far.*